# setVisibility(View.Visible) not working after setting to invisible

Tags: android, visibility

`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` part is working fine, but when I press the radio button to bring back the visibility the items are not appearing. What am I missing?

```
rg = (RadioGroup) myView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.list:{

                    listSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                case R.id.order:{

                    listSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    editSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }

            }
        }
});
```

Comment: You are Using a Switch, add a break before the order case

Comment: @AxelH It worked, thanks.

Comment: next time, tried to check that, this is a common mistake. And debug too ;) add some log on each case (or use debugger). This will be pretty obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use a switch, you need to be carefull about when to stop.

You need to tell when to stop to read, each following case would be execute until you reach a break.

Here :

```
switch (checkedId){
    case R.id.list:
        ...
        break; // *** LINE A
    case R.id.order:
        ...                
}
```

Without **LINE A**, the following lines will be executed too, meaning you will set the view to VISIBLE then INVISIBLE on one call.